# Migrate from a Non Thread Safe php to Thread Safe php server

Tags: php, apache, thread-safety

I have a web project that for compiling it I use a Non Thread Safe version of php,

but my customer have a Thread Safe version of php on his server and when run the

project, there's many errors on each pages.
the question is: how i can fix it without changing server?
can we run Non Thread Safe project on Thread Safe server?
i use ms iis but my customer using last version of xampp.

Comment: Is your customer running the same PHP version with the same modules installed? Errors messages on every page don't at first glance sound threading related.

Comment: no, its running xampp and php version is different from mine

Comment: I'd say it's more likely PHP version and/or missing-module-related than thread safe vs. not. I don't think anyone can help you further without knowing the exact error messages displayed, and the code that gives the errors.

Comment: my php version is PHP Version 5.3.9 and Thread Safety is disabled

Comment: just wait a min, i will get more data

Comment: some err are: undefined index, undefined variables, use of undefined constant p - assumed and so on

Comment: have you checked your not missing an include/require statement?

Comment: and php version is 5.4.4 with Threat safety enabled

Comment: With that limited info, all I can say is that you should pick an error about an undefined <something> and track it backwards to why it doesn't get defined where it's supposed to. Again, doesn't sound threading related at all, so regular debugging techniques should work just fine.

Comment: i think i missing to define something on functions!!!!

Comment: One last thing to check if all else fails. `register_globals` has (finally) been completely removed in PHP 5.4. If you're using that "feature", the code should be rewritten anyway, but just something to check.

Comment: and may be the problem is with some variables in functions inputs

Comment: i dont use that or anything else, just starty function with something like: function fnname($a,$b){ }

Answer (score 1):

Just because it is "thread safe" doesn't mean threads are enabled. XAMPP uses the prefork MPM, which does not use multiple threads. Your errors may be due to something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem
because php error report on my system was off but on the server not
so i never see some miss programing such and I set it on and recheck errors and fix them
and with some part of code i put it off on pages so it done and fix